# Setting Application-level font size in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In Excel I can do something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "Calibri"
```

This replicates the action of navigating to the Home ribbon and choosing a particular font which will be used, to avoid having to programmatically assign different fonts in dozens of places.

Is there an equivalent in PowerPoint?

`ActivePresentation.Styles` returns an error.

I use the object browser and search for `Style` (hoping to find something that is obvious/intuitive) but there are dozens of results, none of them look particularly promising.  Hoping someone else has run in to this before.

Answer (score 0):

With some trial and error, this seems to do the trick:

```
With ActivePresentation
    .SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.MinorFont.Item(1).Name = "Calibri"
End With
```

There is also a `.MajorFont` but it looks like the `.MinorFont` is what I need.

Comment: That'll reset the font for any text that's based on the font theme (ie, that the user added to "click here ..." placeholders).  If you have a shape whose formatting you want to become the default, you can use the shape's SetShapesDefaultProperties method to make it so.  Any new shapes will assume that shape's formatting.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg good catch, that is not really the behavior I want. I've got an old PC with PPT 2003 on it I think I might try and play with the macro recorder there. I'm trying to avoid the need to set individual font shape sizes, but perhaps the indivudal shapes `SetShapesDefaultProperties` will be what I"m looking for.

Comment: so the next question is: Do you need to change the font sizes for everything in the presentation, including existing text?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg no. Only for shapes that the add-in creates. I can do this at run-time on each shape, if necessary, but was hoping to find a better way.

Comment: If you only need to worry about the shapes that your add-in creates, I'd personally stick with setting the font properties at the time the shape's created.  Messing with the defaults is liable to screw things up for the user.  It's not especially difficult to do; yell if you need some example code.

Comment: I think I will just work with the shapes as they are created. Unfortunately, the department in charge of our corporate standards created some Template/THMX files, but they have no real understanding of how these actually interact...

Comment: I have a few friends who specialize in creating proper template/theme files.  They quite literally wrote the book on the subject: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0789749556  Well worth picking up a copy if you do much of anything with templates and themes.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I wish I could recommend that book to them, without stepping on anyone's toes. Sadly, I'm sure such a recommendation would not be well-received -- people don't like being told that they don't know how to do their jobs :)

Comment: Sigh.  Yep, I hear ya.  There's always the "These guys have a lot of neat shortcuts and tools that'll save you lots of time!" dodge.